# Stripping single quotes from Python list

Tags: python

I have a python list that might look like this:

```
['22', '0', '0', '0', '1, 0, 0, 0, 0']
```

I would like for it to look like this:

```
[22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Since the final element isn't an integer, I can't use `map` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419817/remove-single-quotes-from-python-list-item). And using `ast`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302724/remove-single-quotes-in-list-split-string-avoiding-the-quotes), doesn't get me all the way:

```
[22, 0, 0, 0, (1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to parse integers in a list of integers represented as strings that isn't split completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just split on commas then flatten/map int:

```
>>> [int(x) for item in data for x in item.split(',')]
[22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What's the corresponding method if one of the elements is a float?

Comment: @kh_one all depending on what you mean exactly, you can just use `float` instead of `int`

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ['22', '0', '0', '0', '1, 0, 0, 0, 0']
>>> k = ','.join(l)
>>> k
'22,0,0,0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0'
>>> k.split(',')
['22', '0', '0', '0', '1', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
x=['22', '0', '0', '0', '1, 0, 0, 0, 0']

y=eval(str(x).replace("'", ""))
```